# Is it possible to delegate the section rendering with Razor engine to the parent layout when using nested layouts?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a project that is written on the top of Asp.Net Core 2.2 framework and utilizes the Razor template engine to generate the views.

I have the following layout "the grandfather" `_Layout.cshtml`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="author" content="CrestApps.com">
    <meta name="description" content="@ViewData["description"]">
    <meta name="keywords" content="@ViewData["keywords"]">
    <title></title>
    <partial name="_Styles" />
    @RenderSection("Styles", required: false)
</head>
<body>
    <partial name="_Header" />
    <partial name="_CookieConsentPartial" />

    <main role="main">
        @RenderBody()
    </main>

    <partial name="_Footer" />
    <partial name="_Scripts" />

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

This is my second layout `_SecondLayout.cshtml` looks like this which inherits my `_Layout.chtml` as you can see in the code below

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@RenderSection("Styles", required: false)
@RenderSection("Introduction", required: false)

<div class="container-fluid body-content ">
    @RenderBody()
</div>

@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

Then my view will look like this

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_SecondLayout.cshtml";
}

@*.... Some code ....*@
@section scripts {
   // Some JS Code
}
```

The above code will inject the `@section scripts` in the `_SecondLayout` layout. I want it to be injected in the position where `_Layout.cshtml` indicate to keep JS code at the very bottom of the page and also load the script after all other resources have been loaded.

How can I instruct `_SecondLayout` to delegate the `@RenderSection()` section rendering to the upper level?

Comment: Since you are already using `@section scripts` in the `_SecondLayout` try using `@RenderSection("JavaScripts", required: false)` in the `_Layout` and then `@section JavaScripts{}` in the `_SecondLayout`

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, then replace the last line of **_SecondLayout.cshtml**

```
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

with

```
    @section Scripts {
      @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
    }
```